# Waswas I think I may be punished?

Tags: shirk, punishment, kufr

So if you see my other questions it’s similar .  I suffer from was was and OCD and I saw a video on imam Mahdi and I said he’s a slave of Allah and a messenger but I said it out loud but I didn’t mean he’s a messenger but I don’t know if I meant it or not ?? But I said it out loud??? I said that he’s a slave out loud to refute my shirk thoughts from shaytaan . Straight away I refuted it and made istighfar. But I said messenger as I usually say that same statement about Muhammad pbuh when I refute the statement in my mind ? Will I be punished as I said it out loud ?!!! I’m scared !! – in my heart I know Muhammad is the last messenger

Comment: No. Allah is not there to catch you in every mistake you make.

Answer (score 0):

Being scared in front of Allah is beautiful, and anything that takes you towards Allah is good for you. Imagine even if what you said was sin and after that you are scared and you are asking for Allah's forgiveness this shows you are on right way. Allah is merciful, the important is returning to Allah for forgiveness as long as we are alive.